# Is "Abdul Athif" an appropriate name for a Muslim?

Tags: arabic, naming, asma-ul-husna

I am Abdul Athif. Athif means "kind". So I was given as Abdul Athif meaning "Servant of the kind" or "slave of the kind". But I don't find the name Athif in the 99 names of Allah. Is it going against Thawheed? Should I change my name to Athif alone?

Comment: If you want to change your name you should go for Atif. There is no reason to write "th" for Arabic ط .

Answer (score 4):

اللطيف (*Al-Latif*, sometimes transcribed as *Al-Lathif*) is one of the 99 names of Allah, meaning the Subtle, or the Most Kind.  Abdullathif (عبد اللطيف) ‎would be a perfectly valid name for a Muslim.

I do wonder if your name is just a variation of that (transliterations can make that really hard to tell sometimes), with the double-"L" of Abdullathif simplified into a single-"L" (Abdulathif, wherein the "L" gets retained on the Abdul rather than the Lathif when both parts of the name are written separately)

If that's the case, I don't see any problem with keeping the name, although correcting the spelling so it's more clear that it *does* still refer to one of the Names of Allah would be prudent.

If, however, your name is derived from the Arabic عاطف‎ (Atif/Athif, "Kind"), another common Arabic name which is *not* one of the Names of Allah, then yes, retaining the "Abdul" would be problematic, as it involves you identifying as the slave/servant of something that is not Allah.